# Can't find dependent libraries

Tags: dll, native

i am using native lib form OCR and add the jar and put dll in progfile\common files
inspite of that i am getting below error
Please help me ....

### Thanks in Advance

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Common Files: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1751)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1647)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:770)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1005)
    at com.asprise.util.ocr.OCR.loadLibrary(OCR.java:239)
    at com.asprise.util.ocr.OCR.(OCR.java:56)
    at com.readimage.ReadIMG.main(ReadIMG.java:91)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Common Files\AspriseOCR.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1751)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1676)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1030)
    at com.asprise.util.ocr.OCR.loadLibrary(OCR.java:247)
    at com.asprise.util.ocr.OCR.(OCR.java:56)
    at com.readimage.ReadIMG.main(ReadIMG.java:91)

Comment: Seems that other (dependent) libraries are required.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the AspriseOCR.dll file is not in the good path. Try to put it in the windows/system directory where all dll files are stored.

Comment: i already tried for same that u r telling me.. but no use. :(

Comment: Try to check dependencies of AspriseOCR.dll. You are probably missing one. You can find a dependency walker here : http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: done !! problem resolved... but i need to ask u that.. if i use tomcat server and using JSP/Servlet then where i have to put that .dll file.